# Diferences in this two approaches to sleep the excecution in java

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, thread-safety

Except the delay option in the constructor of the `schedule` method, what is the main differences in this two approaches and what of these two approaches is the **best in performance** or **thread-safety** execution??

```
Timer temporizer = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // iterate something
    }
};
temporizer.schedule (task,delay,interval);
```

or a simple

```
while (true){
    // iterate something
    try { 
        Thread.sleep(interval); 
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {...}
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Might not be your current concern but please don't ignore `InterruptedException`s like this.  They are not a mere annoyance we should try to get rid of as quick as possible but an important mechanism to cancel threads.  If one is thrown, your thread should clean up and quit itself.

Comment: @5gon12eder You say it because `catch (InterruptedException ex) { }` ??

Comment: Yes, that's not a good way to deal with that exception.

Comment: @5gon12eder In the question, I write it of this way to simplify the code, obviously that this exception should be treated :)

Comment: Alright, if you already know that, then please ignore my comment.  I've only mentioned it because I see many beginner Java programmers routinely ignoring exceptions or simply printing stack traces and moving on (because that happens to be what Eclipse auto-generates) and it is really bad practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main benefit of the `Timer` approach vs. your sleep-based implementation is that you can cancel it. By doing a `while(true)` in the sleep version, you really don't have a way to cancel it cleanly.

I would also argue, and this is subjective, that the `Timer` approach more clearly expresses what you are trying to do. To clarify though, these are both perfectly understandable and anybody else looking at this code would probably "get it".

Another benefit to the `Timer` approach is that you can encapsulate your iteration logic in the `TimerTask` and keep it separated from the actual timing and scheduling. This would make it easier to test. Even more so if you put it in its own class instead of defining it the way you are there.

Comment: Then, the first approach only gave me a code most understandable?

Comment: Personal opinion, I find that the first approach more clearly states your intent ("I want this to execute every x seconds"). They are both perfectly understandable code.

Comment: @Hector it also gave you a way to cancel the timer and is probably easier to test because of separation of concerns (scheduling vs. doing something)

Answer (score 1):

Timer is dependent on system time so any changes in system time will impact Timer's trigger.

Thread.sleep will not have any impact of system time changes.

Also, Timer crates a queue of tasks which will impact memory, if not garbage collected immediately. More timers will add more objects on heap. Thread.sleep() will only pause the thread so memory impact is low.

Comment: if inside `run` method of `TimerTask` class I call to garbage collector and that is executed in aech iteration?

Comment: yes, it will be executed every time but calling garbage collector from code is not recommended.